# How to view room availability if the availability time is divided into hours In Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want a query that shows the vacant halls available at the specified hours in a schedule for periods. I designed the following tables:

1- Table Main Hall its name( Halls )

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hall_1 |
| 2 | hall_2 |

2- table for Interior Halls its name(Halls_Interior)

| id | IdHalls | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | B |

3- table of rates and periods its name (Halls_Price)

| id | IdHallsInterior | Name | FromTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | rate1 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | rate2 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 1 | rate3 | 9 | 10 |
| 4 | 1 | rate4 | 8 | 10 |
| 5 | 1 | rate5 | 10 | 12 |

If the customer requests to search for halls that are vacant at this time from 9am to 11AM, how will the results appear with him?

I want to combine two periods that fit the time he requested, in case there is not one period that covers the entire time he requested. I used the following query, but it has some problems in terms of results. It works, but the results are incorrect.

The query that was used is:

```
SELECT Halls.Name, Halls_Interior.Name AS Expr1,
       CONCAT(MIN(HP1.FromTime), ' - ', MAX(HP2.EndTime)) AS Expr2,
       SUM(HP1.Price + HP2.Price) AS TotalPrice
FROM Halls
INNER JOIN Halls_Interior ON Halls.Id = Halls_Interior.IdHalls
INNER JOIN Halls_Price HP1 ON Halls_Interior.Id = HP1.IdHallsInterior
INNER JOIN Halls_Price HP2 ON Halls_Interior.Id = HP2.IdHallsInterior
WHERE HP1.FromTime <= 7 AND HP2.EndTime >= 8
   AND HP1.EndTime = HP2.FromTime
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM Halls_Price HP3
       WHERE HP3.IdHallsInterior = Halls_Interior.Id
         AND HP3.FromTime <= HP2.EndTime AND HP3.EndTime > HP2.EndTime
   )
GROUP BY Halls.Name, Halls_Interior.Name
```

The expected and desired results are:

| IdHalls | IdHallsInterior | FromTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 11 |

(from Halls_Price : Take the time from the period you Id:3 and Complete the period with the period you Id:5)..

There is a practical example for modifying the code as put by Brother Ponder Stibbons , thank you
https://dbfiddle.uk/usoIOyII

Comment: Why did you use Join three times?can you show expected

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output

Comment: Modified code and added expected results

Comment: Why did you use Join three times? For if he does not find one period that covers the entire time, he searches for another period that completes the period

Comment: Why not take whole period from row 5? Our goal is to minimize summary price which is not shown?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the period error, I have now modified it

Comment: As you can see in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/usoIOyII) we can still take first hour from row 3 or 4 and last hour from row 5. You want all posibilities or something makes row 3 "better"?

Comment: Great brother, for this example, yes it is now correct, but I want to combine the periods that fit in a row and not three rows, giving the sum of the price for these periods

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, are you after a result where start at 9 and ends at 10?

Comment: A very basic question - Is your third table holding only available halls ? Shouldn’t  you be having some status kind thing which says its available or occupied?

Comment: Your question isn't complete.  Please define more accurately what it means to "fit the time he requested".  There are other cases for which the required result is not defined.  For instance, what happens if the requested start / end time is 8 to 11, since that overlaps the first hour of a 2 hour rate (10 to 12) and also matches 3 other rate periods, (8-9), (9-10) and (8-10).